# Trying to get lower resolution for fun and learning. To bad it's not working

Tags: lubuntu, display, laptop, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I'm trying to see how functional Linux can be at VERY low resolutions, 800x600 is nice but not 16:9. Would be nice to test a 640x480 16:9 equivalent.

I have a laptop with an AMD A6 7th gen laptop APU, I think a 2200 something or another, running lubuntu 20.04. The problem is that when I set a custom resolution, even with a known good resolution but different refresh rate, I only get a black screen.

Does anyone have tips on how to diagnose the issue? Additionally I have a couple different desktop environments installed and have been jumping between them.

Comment: When running Xorg (not Wayland), which resolutions are listed by `xrandr`? It should work to run all those. For example, in my computer the lowest resolution can be selected by `xrandr -s 720x400`

Comment: @sudodus Don't have my computer at the moment but will get back to you on that. I don't remember using the -s option but xrandr did mention the lowest resolution possible being 320x200.

Comment: You are that Lubuntu uses LXQt, which has minimum resolutions for some functions, meaning at really low resolutions (640x480) you'll have OK/CANCEL and like buttons [appearing off screen as you'll be using a lower resolution than LXQt caters for](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1731).